# How can I add a new button into a group with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using the following configuration:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools', 'maximize'] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'justify' ] },
        // { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' }
        // ,
        //{ name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // we don't want too have in a basic editor. We remove them here.
    // config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';
    config.removeButtons = 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Let's have it basic on dialogs as well.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';

    config.extraPlugins = 'insertpre,format,justify,maximize';
```

Everything works okay but the maximize button always goes on the second row of the toolbar. Is there a way I can make it so maximize combines next to some other buttons such as the insertpre button?

Answer (score 0):

You got to configure your toolbar [item by item](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar-section-2) to control the exact position of each single button. By default, Maximize belongs to `tools` group so you can also put the whole group onto the top of the toolbar like this:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'tools', 'mode', 'document', 'doctools', 'maximize'] },
        ...
];
```